# How to build https url in java or mulesoft

Tags: java, ssl, url, https, mule

I am working on a flow in mulesoft. Where I need to Build a https url using a self signed certificate.

Is there any way to create a https url using Java or mulesoft

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is that the flow receives incoming HTTPS requests then use the Mule [HTTP Listener connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-listener-ref) at the beginning of a flow, set the protocol to HTTPS and in the [TLS configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/tls-configuration) set the key store to a Java compatible keystore file that contains the self signed key pair.

Example:

```
<http:listener-connection name="HTTPS_LISTENER" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" protocol="HTTPS">
  <tls:context>
    <tls:key-store path="keystore.jks" password="password"/>
  </tls:context>
</http:listener-connection>

<flow name="someFlow">
    <http:listener path="/test" config-ref="HTTPS_LISTENER"/>
    ...
```

If you mean to perform an HTTPS request in a flow, of a Mule application, then you can do it similarly with the [HTTP Request connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-request-ref). Just use a keystore with the public certificate of the server as the trust store instead.

Comment: No, for a 3 part end point,need to form an https url with JWT token

Comment: Please add all details to the question.